# Questions about particles 「など」 and 「の」

Tags: grammar, particle-の, particle-など

I have came across the below sentence from Nintendo 3DS instruction manual explaining about restriction of using credit card.

ニンテンドーeショップ**など**で**の**クレジットカードの使用や、商品-サービスの購入**など**を制限します。

1. For the first 「など」, I don't think it is necessary to put it in the sentence to be translated as 'place like...' or '....and other places' because Nintendo e-Shop is the only mentioned place where the card can be used. For the second 「など」, likewise, I don't see any other things other than goods and services mentioned in the sentence. Are the both particles 「など」really necessary to be put in the sentence?
2. For the particle 「の」, is it still grammatically correct if I omit it?

Comment: Not sure, but it's probably intended to cover for future stores and services?

Comment: It seems strange or awkward. ( a bit like machine translation) __ Is that the whole sentence?  What comes before and after?

Comment: ^ `It seems strange or awkward. a bit like machine translation` -> そうでしょうか‥そんな感じはしませんが。。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your first question, I agree with nhahtdh that it's probably intended to include stores and services that might become available in the future.

For the second part of your question, I'd say it wouldn't sound natural if you omit it even though we'd understand what it means.

*Just to make it simple, I'll remove `など` in this example.

The main part of the sentence is

> [Something]を制限します。

so, we want to have a noun that fits in the [Something] box, which would be

> [Using credit cards at Nintendo eShop] や [purchasing items/services]

Let's say we omit `の` and say `ニンテンドーeショップで クレジットカードの使用`, this sounds a little strange to me because when I hear a sentence in this form,
`[place]で`, 
I would expect some kind of action/verb performed at the [place] after `[place]`.
For example,

> [ニンテンドーeショップ]で　クレジットカードを**利用する**
>
> [ニンテンドーeショップ]で　商品を**購入する**

But these sentences are a full sentence, not a noun. 
So, we make a little change to them:

> [ニンテンドーeショップ]で**の**　クレジットカード**の利用**
>
> [ニンテンドーeショップ]で**の**　商品**の購入**

or it could be

> [ニンテンドーeショップ]で　クレジットカードを利用すること
>
> [ニンテンドーeショップ]で　商品を購入すること

But this may be slightly less formal.The first one would probably be used more in formal business documents like instruction manual.

So it's just some different ways to make a noun sentence.